# Error Message: The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, macos, talend

installed Talend on mac Catalina for the first time, and added basic **tFileInputExcel**, but when trying to see the content of the excel it shows this error:

```
Error Message: The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Preview error. Some settings must be changed.

Note: Preview errors are generally due to a wrong encoding setting.

org.talend.designer.runprocess.shadow.ShadowFilePreview.preview(ShadowFilePreview.java:90)

org.talend.metadata.managment.ui.utils.ShadowProcessHelper.getCsvArray(ShadowProcessHelper.java:383)

org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.files.excel.ExcelFileStep2Form$PreviewProcessor.nonUIProcessInThread(ExcelFileStep2Form.java:1042)

org.talend.commons.ui.swt.thread.SWTUIThreadProcessor$1.run(SWTUIThreadProcessor.java:74)
```

I have java 11 installed on my mac

> java -version
>
> java version "15" 2020-09-15
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode,
> sharing)

I noticed in project java build it shows only 1.8 version.

How can I solve this?

Comment: what you excel look like? what extention ? version of excel ? Maybe you can cgange encoding setting in advanced setting of the component?

Comment: Well It seems the error is due to the incompatible JDK and JRE version